# How to find substring in Where clause in Sqlite query Android

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

I here want to know the how should I write the `where` clause in `sqlite` query in android as most of the examples I have seen say `address = ?` but I want to check `substring`. Is there a way to check substring of the string present in the database columns.Maybe this is very simple but I didnot find any example of doing this yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes use LIKE operator to check substring in where clause.

Learn [SQL LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Answer (score 5):

Use a string like below in place of **WHERE** clause

-> If the sub string is at begining of column value

```
columnName+" LIKE '"+subString+"%'"
```

-> If the sub string is at end of column value

```
columnName+" LIKE '%"+subString+"'"
```

-> If the sub string is at middle of column value

```
columnName+" LIKE '%"+subString+"%'"
```